# How do I test protocol data transfer speed and data loss?

Tags: protocols

For one of my uni projects I have to test and compare how different protocols handle audio and video data transfer. So I have protocols like RTP, RTMP and RTSP. What should I do to test them myself and get information about data loss, transfer speed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a network impairment tool, for example [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) on Linux,to introduce data loss or bandwidth limitations.